# c++11 thread pool works on windows - blocks on linux

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, c++11, clang

EDIT
I solved my problem by using a single mutex variable in the Shared struct instead of the multiple mutexes in Unique. If someone understands why this works and the other one doesn't (reliably) I will gladly accept an answer.
EDIT

I wrote a simple thread pool with c++11 threads. On windows it behaves as intended but on linux it blocks. I assume that I programmed it wrong and it is just running on windows by coincidence.

The idea is to create the pool once and call run() multiple times, which runs the program once on all available threads, and returns afterwards without destroying the threads. The threads then wait for the next run and so on.

On windows this worked every time I tried it. On linux however only a single thread starts executing the program and after that nothing happens, so run() never returns.

I have included a only slightly condensed version of my source code because I thought the thing might be small enough. If someone is interested in taking a look I suspect loop() and wait_all() in the middle of the code section are the most relevant parts. I have also included the declaration as a reference in case the variable types are not clear from name/context.

```
Pool::Pool(uint32_t num_threads) : num_threads_(num_threads), uniques_(num_threads), threads_(num_threads) {
    shared_.end  = false;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        uniques_[i].wake = false;
        threads_[i] = std::thread(loop, std::ref(uniques_[i]), std::ref(shared_));
    }
}

void Pool::run(Program program) {
    shared_.program = program;
    wake_all();
    wait_all();
}

void Pool::wake_all() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < uniques_.size(); ++i) {
        uniques_[i].wake = true;
    }

    shared_.wake_signal.notify_all();
}

void Pool::wait_all() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads_; ++i) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(uniques_[i].lock);
        uniques_[i].done_signal.wait(locker, [&]{return !uniques_[i].wake;});
    }
}

void Pool::loop(Unique& unique, Shared& shared) {
    for (;;) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(unique.lock);
        shared.wake_signal.wait(locker, [&]{return unique.wake;});

        if (shared.end) {
            break;
        }

        // Do stuff... On linux only a single thread gets here
        shared.program();

        unique.wake = false;
        locker.unlock();
        unique.done_signal.notify_all();
    }
}

// Declaration
class Pool {
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> Program;
    Pool(uint32_t num_threads);
    void run(Program program);
private:
    void wake_all();
    void wait_all();

    struct Unique {
        std::condition_variable done_signal;
        std::mutex lock;
        bool wake;
    };

    struct Shared {
        Program program;
        std::condition_variable wake_signal;
        bool end;
    };

    uint32_t num_threads_;
    Shared shared_;
    std::vector<Unique> uniques_;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads_;

    static void loop(Unique& unique, Shared& shared);
};
```

Comment: Your predicate is backwards in `wait_all`. You want to wait for `wake` to be `true`, not `false`. Also, the `wake_all` function modifies shared state (the `wake` booleans) without holding the lock that protects that state.

Comment: The `Shared` and `Unique` types don't seem to make any sense to me.  `Shared` lacks a mutex next to the condition variable.  Have you debugged your code in the deadlock state?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The reversed predicate in wait_all was intentional. It might be a bit unclear, but the idea is to wait for wake == true in wake_all and for wake == false in wait_all. The variable doubles for "wake me" and "I'm done". At least that was the plan.

Comment: @Yakk: My intention was to have one signal that wakes all threads. Can this not be achieved like this?

Comment: @Yakk The mutex is in `Unique`.

Comment: I switched to using a single mutex in shared instead of multiple mutexes in the unique elements. This solved the problem for the linux build.
To be honest I haven't understood why I need a mutex in the first place.
I will try the revised version on windows tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, but there are many `unique` mutexes.  Which guards the shared condition variable?  None do so reliably, as far as I can tell.  My guess is B_old doesn't understand the relationship between mutexes, condition variables, and the message they guard?  When working with multi-threaded code, *testing is not enough*.  "It worked when I tried it" is a recipe for code that will fail in production.  Test, *and* construct logical arguments that your code will behave properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are violating the standard's requirements for calling `wait`:

> void wait(unique_lock& lock);
>
> Requires: lock.owns_lock() is true and lock.mutex() is locked by the calling thread, and either:
>
> — no other thread is waiting on this condition_variable object or
>
> — lock.mutex() returns the same value for each of the lock arguments supplied by all concurrently waiting (via wait or timed_wait) threads.

You can have concurrently waiting threads whose `lock` refers to a different `mutex`. So you don't meet the prerequisites for calling `wait` on a `condition_variable`.

I believe you could use a `condition_variable_any`, which doesn't have this requirement.